# Adding Lombok plugin to IntelliJ project

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I'm trying to add Lombok to my Spring Boot project in IntelliJ IDEA. So far, I've

1. added the plugin under **Settings** - **Plugins** (version 0.13.16)
2. added `compile('org.projectlombok:lombok')` to my Gradle dependencies
3. enabled annotation processing

It still doesn't recognize either the Lombok import or the annotations.

What am I missing?

**Solved:**

I had to run an update on my Gradle file.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your solution?

Answer (score 77):

You need to **Enable Annotation Processing** on **`IntelliJ IDEA`**

**`> Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Annotation Processors`**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. A bit weird that you have to enable this option after installing the Lombok plugin, though. They should have at least pointed to this option in their instructions.

Comment: I don't have it enabled and Lombok is recognized (after installing the plugin and restarting). Maybe this is not necessary anymore?

Comment: Adding the Lombok plugin is necessary for runtime usage. Activating the annotation processing is necessary for compile time usage to get rid of the compiler warnings in the editor window.

Answer (score 42):

To add the Lombok IntelliJ plugin to add lombok support IntelliJ:

- Go to File > Settings > Plugins
- Click on Browse repositories...
- Search for Lombok Plugin
- Click on Install plugin
- Restart IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: This is correct approach followed by @Henrik's steps and enabling "Annotation processing" under `Build, Execution and deployment` section in `Settings`.

Answer (score 15):

Be sure to activate the plugin for the project in the Intellij settings.

1. Click **Settings  Other Settings  Lombok Plugin**.
2. Ensure **Enable Lombock plugin...** is checked.

[image: Lombok Plugin Settings]

Comment: And restart after plugin installation didn't work?

Comment: No, oddly enough.

Comment: after enabling the lombok error messages i get ' Lombok Dependency is missing ~ Project "dsRngChecker" does not seem to have lombok dependency added. ' tried various versions of compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:0.13.16")

Comment: You have added lombok like the describe here: https://projectlombok.org/mavenrepo/? _compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.12"_

Answer (score 9):

To install the plugin manually, try:

1. [Download](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok/versions) Lombok zip file (ensure Lombok matches the IDE version).
2. Select **Preferences  Plugins  Install Plugins from Disk**.

[image: IntelliJ Plugin Preferences Dialog]

Answer (score 5):

There is a lot of really helpful info posted here, but there is one thing that all the posts seem to have wrong. I could not find any 'Settings' option under 'Files', and I hunted around for 10 minutes looking through all the menus until I found the settings under 'IntelliJ IDE'  -> 'Preferences'.

I don't know if I am using a differing OS version or IntelliJ version from other posters, or if it is because I am a stupid Windows user that doesn't know that settings == preferences on a mac (Did I miss the memo?), but I hope this helps you if you aren't finding the paths that other posts are suggesting.

Comment: ...and that's why I love people posting screenshots; the world's between win and mac and its wordings annoyances are a step clearer then ;-) I also think that these troubles sometimes consumes too much time. Did anyone mention the differences between versions of a software ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I would like to add that in my case (My OS is Linux Mint and using IntelliJ IDEA). My compiler complaining about these annotations I was using: @Data @RequiredArgsConstructor, even though I had installed and activated the Lombok plugin.[Install Lombok in IntelliJ Idea](https://projectlombok.org/setup/intellij).
I am using Maven. So I had to add this dependency in my configuration file (pom.xml file):

```
dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

If after installing the `lombok intellij plugin` and enabling annotation processing, if your getter and setters are still not recognised in intellij, do check if the `plugin` version is compatible with the `intellij` version you use.

It is listed under the Downloads section:

- https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok-plugin
- https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok/versions

Answer (score 2):

For me it didn't work after doing all of the steps suggested in the question and in the top answer. Initially the import didn't work, and then when I restarted IntelliJ, I got these messages from the Gradle Plugin:

```
Gradle DSL method not found: 'annotationProcessor()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'wq-handler-service' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.2 and sync project</li><li>The project 'wq-handler-service' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file</li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin</li>
```

This was weird because I don't develop for Android, just using IntelliJ for Mac OS.

To be fair, my `build.gradle` file had these lines in the `dependencies` section, which I copied from a colleague:

```
compileOnly group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.16.20'
annotationProcessor group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.16.20'
```

After checking versions, the only thing that completely solved my problem was adding the below to the `plugins` section of `build.gradle`, which I found on this [page](https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle):

```
id 'net.ltgt.apt' version '0.15'
```

Looks like it's a

> Gradle plugin making it easier/safer to use Java annotation processors

([ltgt plugin page](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/net.ltgt.apt))

Answer (score 1):

I just found how.

I delete the first occurrence of lombok `@Slf4j` or `log` where the compiler complains, and wait for the warning(the red bubble) of IDEA, suggesting "add the lombok.extern.Slf4j.jar to classpath". Since then all goes well. It seems IDEA likes to complain about lombok.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after updating IntelliJ IDE, the fix was: delete existed plugin lombok and install it again (the newest version),