# lombok annotation is not wokring in intellij19.3

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok, openjdk-12

It's seem lombok annotation is not working.

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor

public class HelloResponseDto {
    private final String name;
    private final int amount;
}
```

and here is output

```
> Task :cleanTest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileJava FAILED
C:\Users\tahun\IdeaProjects\spring-tutorial\src\main\java\org\example\springboot\web\dto\HelloResponseDto.java:10: error: variable name not initialized in the default constructor
    private final String name;
                         ^
C:\Users\tahun\IdeaProjects\spring-tutorial\src\main\java\org\example\springboot\web\dto\HelloResponseDto.java:11: error: variable amount not initialized in the default constructor
    private final int amount;
```

I'm working with Intellij so I also checked
**Settings > Compiler > Annotation Processors > Enable annotaion processing**

and i also add  **compile('org.projectlombok:lombok')** in my build.gradle

Is there any solutions?

==more==
I also installed lombok plugin.

Comment: Building with gradle and then enabling annotation processing in your IDE won't help. You will need to configure lombok in gradle to have the annotation processor work. Have you followed [the official guide for lombok with gradle](https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle)?

Comment: @M.Deinum It's working tnk very much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `lombok` plugin to Intellij. You can use following url to download.

[Lombok Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok/)

Comment: try adding `@AllArgsConstructor` annotation as well just under `@Getter` annotation

Comment: sorry then I don't know how to help. You can have look at this, he seems had a solution. https://github.com/tbroyer/gradle-apt-plugin/issues/10

Answer (score -1):

Install the needed plugin for Lombok...

Lombok is not supported out of the box.

Answer (score -1):

You can add the lombok plugin - https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok/

Go to Setting --> plugins and search for lombok and add the plugin.

Restart and check. IntelliJ should not report any error of lombok.

Answer (score -1):

This problem is resolved, please have a look into the below StackOverflow URL

- [Adding Lombok plugin to IntelliJ project [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41161076/adding-lombok-plugin-to-intellij-project)
- [Lombok annotations do not compile under Intellij idea [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006937/lombok-annotations-do-not-compile-under-intellij-idea)
- [Can't compile project when I'm using Lombok under IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424364/cant-compile-project-when-im-using-lombok-under-intellij-idea)

Download IntelliJ Plugin  [Lombok IntelliJ plugin](https://projectlombok.org/setup/intellij)

Answer (score -1):

its very easy to configure lombok in IntelliJ using below steps:

1.Go to Setting --> plugins and search for lombok and add the plugin.
2. restart the intelliJ
3. check if working or not , if still not working then restart your system due to some time not able to configure new plugin properly.