# Cannot find symbol (all the constructors, getters and setters) in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, lombok

My project was working fine earlier, but when I open this in STS and then opened it in IntelliJ, it started giving me this error. I was searching for a solution but didn't got any. Anyone, please help me.

Also, **I have already installed the Lombok plugin in my IntelliJ**.

**Error picture**

[image]

My **pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>training-management-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>training-management-server</name>
    <description>Backend for Training management</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.206</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.auth0/java-jwt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.18.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.project-lombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**UserController**

```
package com.trainingmanagementserver.api;

import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier;
import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;
import com.auth0.jwt.interfaces.DecodedJWT;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.trainingmanagementserver.entity.*;
import com.trainingmanagementserver.exception.ApiRequestException;
import com.trainingmanagementserver.message.ResponseFile;
import com.trainingmanagementserver.message.ResponseMessage;
import com.trainingmanagementserver.repository.TraineesTrainerRepository;
import com.trainingmanagementserver.repository.UserCredentialsRepository;
import com.trainingmanagementserver.service.AssignmentDetailsService;
import com.trainingmanagementserver.service.FileDBService;
import com.trainingmanagementserver.service.UserCredentialsService;
import com.trainingmanagementserver.service.UserDetailService;
import com.trainingmanagementserver.utility.Utility;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import static org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION;
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
//@Validated
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:8080")
public class UserController {
    private final UserCredentialsService userCredentialsService;
    private final UserDetailService userDetailService;
    private final UserCredentialsRepository userCredentialsRepository;
    private final TraineesTrainerRepository traineesTrainerRepository;
    private final AssignmentDetailsService assignmentDetailsService;
    private final FileDBService fileDBService;

    @PostMapping("/auth/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<UserCredentialsEntity> saveUser(@RequestBody UserCredentialsEntity userCredentialsEntity) throws ApiRequestException{
        URI uri = URI.create(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().path("/api/auth/signup").toUriString());
        var username = userCredentialsRepository.findByUsername(userCredentialsEntity.getUsername());
        var email = userCredentialsRepository.findByEmail(userCredentialsEntity.getEmail());
        if(username == null  && email == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.created(uri).body(userCredentialsService.userCredentialsSave(userCredentialsEntity));
        } else if(username != null && email != null) {
            throw new ApiRequestException("Username and Email already exist");
        }
        else if(username != null){
            throw new ApiRequestException("Username already exist");
        }
        throw new ApiRequestException("Email already exist");
    }

    @PostMapping("/trainee/addBulk")
    public ResponseEntity<List<UserCredentialsEntity>> addBulkTrainees(@RequestBody List<UserCredentialsEntity> bulkUserCredentialsEntity, HttpServletRequest request) throws ApiRequestException{
        URI uri = URI.create(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().path("/api/role").toUriString());
        String username = (new Utility()).getUsernameFromToken(request);
        int trainerId = userCredentialsRepository.findByUsername(username).getId();
        bulkUserCredentialsEntity.forEach(trainee -> {
            var checkUsername = userCredentialsRepository.findByUsername(trainee.getUsername());
            var checkEmail = userCredentialsRepository.findByEmail(trainee.getEmail());
            if(checkUsername != null || checkEmail != null) {
                throw new ApiRequestException("Invalid Entry");
            }
        });
        var savedTrainees = userCredentialsService.addBulkTrainees(bulkUserCredentialsEntity);
        savedTrainees.forEach(trainees -> {
            int traineeId = trainees.getId();
            TraineesTrainer traineesTrainer = new TraineesTrainer();
            traineesTrainer.setTraineeId(traineeId);
            traineesTrainer.setTrainerId(trainerId);
            traineesTrainerRepository.save(traineesTrainer);
            userCredentialsService.addRoleToUser("ROLE_TRAINEE", trainees.getUsername());
        });
        return ResponseEntity.created(uri).body(savedTrainees);
    }

    @GetMapping("/trainee/all")
    public ResponseEntity<List<UserMerged>> getAllTrainees(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String username = (new Utility().getUsernameFromToken(request));
        if(username.isEmpty()) throw new ApiRequestException("Username not present");
        var trainerId = userCredentialsRepository.findByUsername(username).getId();
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(userCredentialsService.showTraineesEnrolled(trainerId));
    }

    @PostMapping("/role")
    public ResponseEntity<Role> saveRole(@RequestBody Role role) {
        URI uri = URI.create(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().path("/api/role").toUriString());
        return ResponseEntity.created(uri).body(userCredentialsService.roleSave(role));
    }

    @GetMapping("/register/check")
    public ResponseEntity<?> checkRegister(HttpServletRequest request) throws ApiRequestException{
        try {
            String username = (new Utility()).getUsernameFromToken(request);
            int userId = userCredentialsRepository.findByUsername(username).getId();
            Map<String, Boolean> response = new HashMap<>();
            if (userDetailService.fetchUserDetails(userId).isPresent()) {
                response.put("isPresent", true);
            } else {
                response.put("isPresent", false);
            }
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(response);
        } catch (ApiRequestException exception) {
            throw new ApiRequestException("Token is mismatch");
        }
    }

    @PostMapping("/role/addToUser")
    public ResponseEntity<?> addRoleToUser(@RequestBody RoleToUserForm roleForm) throws ApiRequestException {
        try {
            userCredentialsService.addRoleToUser(roleForm.getRoleName(), roleForm.getUsername());
            return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ApiRequestException("Not able to add role to the user");
        }
    }

    @PostMapping("/me")
    public ResponseEntity<?> saveUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserDetailsEntity userDetailsEntity, HttpServletRequest request) {
//        System.out.println("Printing result "+result);
//        if(result.hasErrors()) {
//            Map<String, BindingResult> errors = new HashMap<>();
//            errors.put("error", result);
//            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(errors);
//        }
        URI uri = URI.create(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().path("/api/user/detail").toUriString());
        String username = (new Utility()).getUsernameFromToken(request);
        int userId = userCredentialsRepository.findByUsername(username).getId();
        userDetailsEntity.setId(userId);
        return ResponseEntity.created(uri).body(userDetailService.save(userDetailsEntity));
    }

    @GetMapping("/me")
    public ResponseEntity<UserMerged> fetchUserDetails(HttpServletRequest request) throws ApiRequestException {
        try {
            String username = (new Utility()).getUsernameFromToken(request);
            int userId = userCredentialsRepository.findByUsername(username).getId();
            if (userDetailService.fetchUserDetails(userId).isPresent()) {
                UserDetailsEntity userDetailsEntity = userDetailService.fetchUserDetails(userId).get();
                UserCredentialsEntity userCredentialsEntity = userCredentialsRepository.findByUsername(username);
                UserMerged userMerged = new UserMerged();
                userMerged.setUser_detail(userDetailsEntity);
                userMerged.setUser_credential(userCredentialsEntity);
                return ResponseEntity.ok().body(userMerged);
            }
        } catch (ApiRequestException exception) {
            throw new ApiRequestException("Token mismatch");
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
    }

    @GetMapping("/token/refresh")
    public void refreshToken(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION);
        log.info(authorizationHeader);
        if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            try {
                String refresh_token = authorizationHeader.substring("Bearer ".length());
                log.info(refresh_token);
                Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("secret".getBytes());
                JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm).build();
                DecodedJWT decodedJWT = verifier.verify(refresh_token);
                String username = decodedJWT.getSubject();
                UserCredentialsEntity userCredentialsEntity = userCredentialsService.getUser(username);
                String access_token = JWT.create()
                        .withSubject(userCredentialsEntity.getUsername())
                        .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 10 * 60 * 1000))
                        .withIssuer(request.getRequestURL().toString())
                        .withClaim("roles", userCredentialsEntity.getRoles().stream().map(Role::getName).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                        .sign(algorithm);
                Map<String, String> tokens = new HashMap<>();
                tokens.put("access_token", access_token);
                tokens.put("refresh_token", refresh_token);
                response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
                new ObjectMapper().writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), tokens);
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                response.setHeader("error", exception.getMessage());
                response.setStatus(FORBIDDEN.value());
                Map<String, String> error = new HashMap<>();
                error.put("error", exception.getMessage());
                response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
                new ObjectMapper().writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), error);
            }
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Refresh token required!");
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/user/all")
    public List<UserCredentialsEntity> fetchUsers() {
        return userCredentialsService.fetchUsersCredentials();
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/user/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") int userId) {
        userCredentialsService.deleteUser(userId);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("User is deleted Successfully!!");
    }

    @PostMapping("/assignment/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseMessage> uploadFile(@RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file,@RequestParam("title") String title, @RequestParam("description") String description, @RequestParam("total_credit") int total_credit, @RequestParam("due_date") String due_date, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String senderUsername = (new Utility()).getUsernameFromToken(request);
        int trainerId = userCredentialsRepository.findByUsername(senderUsername).getId();
        var savedAssignment = assignmentDetailsService.save(new AssignmentDetail(trainerId, title, description, total_credit, due_date, true));
        String message = "Assignment Uploaded Successfully";
        if(file != null) {
            try {
                fileDBService.store(file, savedAssignment.getId());
            } catch(IOException exception) {
                message = "Could not upload the file " + file.getOriginalFilename();
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED).body(new ResponseMessage(message));
            }
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new ResponseMessage(message));
    }

    @GetMapping("/files/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseFile> getFile(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        var file = fileDBService.getFileByFileId(id);
        String fileDownloadUri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder
                .fromCurrentContextPath()
                .path("/files/")
                .path(Integer.toString(file.getId()))
                .toUriString();

        ResponseFile responseFile = new ResponseFile(file.getName(),fileDownloadUri, file.getType(), file.getData().length);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(responseFile);
    }

}

@Data
class RoleToUserForm {
    private String username;
    private String roleName;
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: Does `UserCredentialsEntity` have any lombok annotations?

Comment: Yes, I have used ```@Getter```, ```@Setter```, and ```@ToString``` annotations.

Comment: sometimes the ide is not able to recognize the lombok statements, have you ensured that lombok plugin is detected by intellij ? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41161076/adding-lombok-plugin-to-intellij-project

Comment: Already done this. Yet not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For IntelliJ Idea, when using Lombok you have to enable annotation processing.

- Preferences (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>)

  - Build, Execution, Deployment

    - Compiler

      - Annotation Processors

        - Enable annotation processing

---

If the problem still persist:

Add version 1.18.16.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
<artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
<version>1.18.16</version> 
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have already done this. In fact, it was working fine earlier, but after opening the project in STS, it's not working in IntelliJ also.

Comment: Have you restarted IDE?

Comment: Yes, many times.

Comment: Please install Lombok in the plugin.

Comment: I have installed already.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Gradle do not forget to add

annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Apache maven with JDK9+ with module-info.java

you will need to add to the compiler plugin the **path**

for example

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>1.18.26</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

ref: https://projectlombok.org/setup/maven