# Lombok dependency added but @Getter, @Setter not working for classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml, lombok

I copied my project from one laptop to another. Lombok dependency is already added in its pom.xml file. But now, the java classes in my project using @getter, @setter are not are not able to generate get..() and set..() functions when their objects are created and hence build is failing.

Example:

User class

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name="posts")
public class Post {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer postId;


@Column(name="post_title", length=100, nullable=false)
private String title;

@Column(length=1000)
private String content;

private Date date;
private String imageName;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="category_id")
private Category category;

@ManyToOne
private User user;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Comment> comments =  new HashSet<>();
```

}

Place where its giving error:

```
Post post = this.modelMapper.map(postDto, Post.class);
    post.setDate(new Date());
    post.setImageName("default.png");
    post.setCategory(category);
    post.setUser(user);
    Post newPost = this.postRepo.save(post);
```

All the set methods used above are throwing "method not found exception".

How to deal with this issue?? Help!!

Comment: I managed to solve this by installing lombok plugin in intellij. Refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41161076/adding-lombok-plugin-to-intellij-project

Comment: If you are using eclipse and maven project , run maven clean and then maven build. It should fix the issue. Also try restarting the IDE

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lombok added but getters and setters not recognized in Intellij IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729384/lombok-added-but-getters-and-setters-not-recognized-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: Do we need to externally download lombok plugin even if its mentioned in pom.xml?? I remember I had never installed lombok plugin in sts/eclipse before??

Comment: not needed in eclipse, it was needed for me in intellij

Comment: I installed lombok plugin externally and all erros are gone. Thanks for help. I still have one doubt, why do need to install lombok plugin manually even if its dependency is added in pom.xml???

Comment: weird. For eclipse you do not need to install the plugin , only for intellij you need it. Same is mentioned in below doc-https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-ide